# PhpStorm SASS я в главном файле сделал @import других файлов. А в них обращаюсь к функциям/миксинам из главного. IDE выдает Warning'и. Как исправить?

Tags: phpstorm, sass

У меня есть один главный файл CSS. Я подключаю его в HTML. В него пишутся стили от SASS файлов.
Есть также главный SASS файл. В нем происходит `import` всех других SASS файлов. В нем также объявлены функции, переменные, миксины.
Когда я в импортируемых файлах обращаюсь к функциям / переменным / миксинам из главного файла, PhpStorm выдает:

> Warning: "Element 'lg-max' is resolved only by name without use of explicit imports more... (Ctrl+F1)".

Однако если я зажму `Ctrl` и щелкну по функции / переменной / миксину, IDE находит его.
Как сделать так, чтобы PhpStorm не выдавал Warning'и там, где не нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка доступности эедемента через импорты в "главном" файле слишклм дорогостоящая, т.к. для каждого элемента в проекте необходимо проверять все его включения, двигаясь не по цепочке импортов, а в обратном порядке. Поэтому используется следующий алгоритм:

- если объявление переменной (функции, миксина) найдено в текущем файле или файлах, доступных из текущего по цепочке импортов, никаких ошибок не возникает, элемент подсвечивается как `Resolved`

  - если объявление не найдено, оно ищется в индексе просто по имени. В случае успеха элемент помечается как `Resolved by name only`, и выдается предупреждение `Element 'xxx' is resolved only by name without use of explicit imports`
  - если элемент не удалось найти на предыдущих этапах,  он помечается как `Unresolved`.

Вы можете отключить инспекцию **Resolved by name only** (**Settings | Editor | Inspections Sass/SCSS**), если Вы уверенв, что все элементы на самом деле импортированы, и не хотите видеть warning

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А вы не подскажете, почему PhpStorm также и вот здесь warning выдает:
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store">
Wrong attribute value.

Comment: проблема в том, что meta.rnc (HTML5 схема, используемая для валидации) включает очень небольшой набор значений, разрешенных для этого атрибута. Попробуйте любой online валидатор (они все почти те же схемы используют) - https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea, скажем. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14609